# Fundamental question on test for normal distribution

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I have a fundamental question on statistical tests, particularly tests for normal distribution. As I understand statistical tests in general, they have a null hypothesis $H_0$ (e.g. the samples were drawn from a normal distribution) and an alternative hypothesis $H_1$ (e.g. the samples were not drawn from a normal distribution). If the test is significant ($p < p_\alpha$) one can reject $H_0$ and assume that $H_1$ is true. However, if the test is not significant, one can *not* automatically assume that $H_0$ is true.

Now, all tests for normal distribution that I read about have a $H_0$ that the samples were drawn from a normal distribution. Hence, the only thing you can do with these tests is to assume that the samples were not drawn from a normal distribution if the test is significant. You *can't* assume that the samples are drawn from a normal distribution if the test is *not* significant. But that's what everybody seems to be doing.

Is there anything fundamentally wrong with my understanding of statistical tests? How can I "prove" that a given sample was drawn from a normal distribution?

Comment: There is nothing fundamentally wrong in the asymmetry you have noticed in test statistics, and you can find a very informed explanation [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/85914/67822).

Answer (score 1):

When the test statistic falls in the significant region, we reject the null hypothesis that the samples are drawn from a Gaussian distribution.

When the test statistic does not fall in the significant region, we *fail to reject the null hypothesis* that samples are drawn from a Gaussian distribution - we cannot say anything more.

Even this 'failing to reject' has a lot of use cases.

For e.g. in the output of OLS regression where $\beta_i$'s (the coefficients) are estimated, we see the p-values reported. 
These p-values are nothing but they are rejecting the null hypothesis that $\beta_i = 0$. Essentially, they are reporting a significant linear relationship.

With regards to your question, your understanding is correct.

One can never be 100% sure that a sample comes from a Gaussian distribution. We can only give a confidence level. Typically, more the sample size, better the confidence level.

However, there are variations across each of these statistical tests readily available in statistical software. Certain tests are 'good' for detecting certain aspects based on their [statistical power.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_(statistics))

Comment: So there seems to be no way to apply e.g. Student's t-test (which requires normally distributed data) with small sample sizes because one cannot "prove" or assume that the data is normally distributed?

Comment: @Mouagip: Student's t-test is used to test if the mean parameter $\mu$ is equal to some number, say, $c$, i.e. the $H_0: \mu = c$. The underlying assumption in t-test is that the samples follow a Gaussian distribution. In order to check whether the data comes a Gaussian distribution or not, we can do a separate test - some of the tests for normality are Anderson Darling Test, KS test, etc. 
If these tests for normality do not reject the null hypothesis that the samples came from a Gaussian distribution, then you can safely go ahead with a t-test..

Comment: @Mouagip: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test

Comment: "If these tests for normality do not reject the null hypothesis that the samples came from a Gaussian distribution, then you can safely go ahead with a t-test." - This is what I'd like to confirm since the fact that you can't assume $H_0$ if you can't reject $H_0$ seems to mean rather the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Your can assume that both hypothesis belong to same distribution or population because both hypothesis can be used to approximate that distribution.

An example - A company checks that mean water in their manufactured water bottle is about 997 ml with variance k.But after they replaced the manufacturing machine with another same machine, they note that the mean water in a water bottle is about 995ml with variance k.You may assume that both population folows normal distribution.Test at 5% level of significance whether new mean can be considered.

In this you might end with conclusion that new mean can be conidered because $H_a$ 
fails.These both contain means that are very close so one might assume that they come from same distribution if population size of both distribution is significantly large.

To test whether both hypothesis come from same distribution you can use chi sqaured test.
You can find more about chi squared test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test

Comment: But how ca I apply e.g. Student's t-test (which requires normally distributed data) with small sample sizes where normal distribution cannot be assumed because of the sample size? If you can only test for *not* normally distributed data, there seems to be no way to do this.

Comment: t-test is mostly used for finding out conifidence level for small sample sizes.https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi348rzzLbkAhUJM48KHa-vBegQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstats.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F122768%2Fstatistic-t-test-t-table&psig=AOvVaw1aVKN6GSV-kZp4JMCRO6Nw&ust=1567667015083467. t-test can be only be used for values like 0.975. You can apply t-test if $n$ is sufficiently small.

Comment: That is correct but the t-test requires normally distributed data as well. How can I show that my data is normally distributed if there are only tests available to show that the data is *not* normally distributed?

Comment: Please upvote if you think my answer helped you

Comment: The t-test assumes that the means of the different samples are normally distributed. it does not assume that the population is normally distributed

Comment: Hope this helps

Comment: I don't think this is correct. How can the the means of two samples be normally distributed?

Comment: By the central limit theorem, means of samples from a population with finite variance approach a normal distribution regardless of the distribution of the population. Rules of thumb say that the sample means are basically normally distributed as long as the sample size is at least 20 or 30. But if size is smaller then for a t-test , the population distribution would have to be approximately normal.